# Order by Date in MySQL & PHP and giving importance to today date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make an order by date to get the comments of user, but I want to give the importance to today date

if there's a comment today show it first and make the ordering with date for the rest.

I try to make this but always give me an error in syntax

```
SELECT *
FROM comment
ORDER BY IF(`DATE_TIME_COMMENT` = CURRENT_DATE())
```

is there any solution ?

Comment: You could simply do: `SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY DATE_TIME_COMMENT DESC`. Meaning the last comment first.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but I have a problem, because I get the possibility to less a comment and lunch it in specific date, in this case if I make your code, it get the comments from future not in current date

Comment: It is possible to have a future comment date?

Comment: Comments from the future? Wow... Ok, let's assume your server can time travel, then you need to restrict the select with a `WHERE` clause, like so: `SELECT * FROM comment WHERE DATE_TIME_COMMENT <= CURRENT_DATE() ORDER BY DATE_TIME_COMMENT DESC` or something to that effect depending on the exact type of your date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort by a `CASE` returning "something lower", if `date_time_comment` is equal to `current_date()` and "something higher" else. Then, second, sort by `date_time_comment`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM comment
       ORDER BY CASE date_time_comment
                  WHEN current_date()
                    THEN 0
                  ELSE
                    1
                END,
                date_time_comment;
```

(Possibly add `DESC` after `date_time_comment` in the `ORDER BY` clause, if you want to have newest comments first.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't have comments with future date, just order by date

```
SELECT * FROM comment ORDER BY DATE_TIME_COMMENT DESC
```

If you can have future date, and want to order first the today date, then comments with other date than today, one way to do this is with a `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 1 as order, c.* FROM comment c WHERE DATE_TIME_COMMENT = CURRENT_DATE()
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 as order, c.* FROM comment c WHERE DATE_TIME_COMMENT <> CURRENT_DATE()
) order by order asc, DATE_TIME_COMMENT desc
```

That you get first the today comments, then other comments order by date